# Как сгенерировать непересекающиеся окружности?

Tags: c#, winforms, геометрия

У меня есть класс Ball, его метод  Draw, который рисует окружность. При клике на форму я создаю обьект класса и вызываю метод, который рисует окружность в рандомном месте рандомного размера. Вопрос такой, каким образом предотвратить генерацию окружностей так, чтобы они не пересекались при создании?

Comment: Две окружности имеют координаты центра и радиус, подробней график и формулу можно найти тут: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Answer (score 5):

Две окружности не пересекаются, если **расстояние между их центрами больше суммы их радиусов**

Пусть наша окружность представлена структурой:

```
struct Circle
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double R { get; set; }
}
```

Все наши уже сгенерированные окружности хранятся в некоторой коллекции:

```
List<Circle> circles = new List<Circle>();
```

Тогда, генерацию новой окружности, которая не пересекается ни с какой другой, можно выполнить следующим образом:

```
Circle nextCircle;
do
{
    nextCircle = new Circle
    {
        // Здесь мы генерируем координаты центра и радиус
    };
}
while (circles.All(c => // Для всех уже существующих окружностей
    Sqr(c.R + nextCircle.R) > Sqr(c.X - nextCircle.X) + Sqr(c.Y - nextCircle.Y) ));
//  квадрат суммы радиусов            квадрат расстояния между центрами
circles.Add(nextCircle);
```

Здесь я использую вспомогательную функцию возведения в квадрат:

```
double Sqr(double x) => x * x;
```

Обратите внимание, для того чтобы не извлекать корень при расчете расстояния между центрами окружностей, я возвожу обе части неравенства (которое выделено в первом предложении) в квадрат, это законно, т. к. расстояния на плоскости заведомо неотрицательны.

---

Если необходимо учитывать также варианты, в которых одна окружность полностью лежит внутри другой, то надо модифицировать условие таким образом:

```
do
{
    ...
}
while (circles.All(c =>
       Sqr(c.R + nextCircle.R) > Sqr(c.X - nextCircle.X) + Sqr(c.Y - nextCircle.Y)
    || Sqr(c.R - nextCircle.R) > Sqr(c.X - nextCircle.X) + Sqr(c.Y - nextCircle.Y) ));
```

Второе условие это преобразованное выражение неравенства: **расстояние между центрами плюс меньший радиус меньше большего радиуса**

Comment: Есть ещё вариант, когда одна окружность полностью лежит внутри другой, тогда они тоже не пересекаются. Могу дополнить ответ, если такой вариант тоже нужно учесть.

Comment: Дополните, это важный случай.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, готово!

Comment: Вопрос пять месяцев висел без хорошего ответа. Стоило сделать внятный заголовок — ответ появился. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, дело не в заголовке, а в том, что этот вопрос вообще "всплыл", да еще и с указанием модератора на качество ответа. Я просто, например, вглубь на 5 месяцев вообще не хожу

Comment: @Андрей: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674245/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-listview

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативная реализация, которая гарантированно находит новую окружность за одну итерацию.

Простая идея состоит в том, что все наши окружности будут вложены одна в другую, и для добавления новой окружности нам достаточно, чтобы самая большая из существующих окружностей лежала полностью внутри.

Пусть радиус этой окружности `R`, тогда мы отступаем от её центра на `R + 1`, и добавляем окружность с центром в полученной точке радиуса `2R + 2`.

Получается такой код:

```
var lastCircle = circles.Last();
var R = lastCircle.Radius + 1;
var newCircle = new Circle(center: lastCircle.Center + new Vector(R, 0), radius: 2 * R);
circles.Add(newCircle);
```

Comment: добавил одну окружность с центром в т. (0, 0) радиуса 1, затем сгенерировал по вашему алгоритму еще 9 окружностей, вот что получилось: http://imgur.com/ir6UH1b Думаю, это условиям задачи не удовлетворяет...

Comment: @Андрей: Согласен, баг, радиус надо было больше увеличивать. Поправил код.