# WPF TextBox: Прокрутка при вводе

Tags: c#, wpf

Стиль:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
<Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,0,0,0"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsTabStop="False" IsEnabled="False"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Как можно добавить в этот стиль функциональность прокрутки в конец по мере ввода? Т.е. когда текста выходит за пределы видимости в поле, нужно выполнить прокрутку в конец поля ввода, чтобы пользователь видел что он вводит.

---

**UPD:** Можно попробовать вот так:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    Rect rect = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textBox.CaretIndex == 0 ? 0 : textBox.CaretIndex - 1);
    textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(rect.Left);
}
```

Однако, после 30-34 символов (13 px, Segoe UI) каретка начинает забегать вперёд, и её снова не видно.

Comment: Разве она не автоматом прокручивает?

Comment: Вроде нормально прокручивается, покажите всю разметку

Comment: Это весь код: `<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,120,0,0" Width="120">`

Comment: И у меня это TextBox не прокручивает в конец по мере ввода.

Comment: Вот почему в WPF нет такого метода как `TextBox.ScrollToCaret`?..

Comment: @AGS17: Да, автоматом она в WPF не прокручивается. В WinForms вроде как да, каретка всегда в поле зрения пользователя. Кстати, добавил свежей информации в свой вопрос.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksjO0.gif

Comment: *В смысле что при данном переопределении стиля. Попробуйте используя мной представленный стиль.

Comment: @D.Stark: По умолчанию шаблон выглядит так: https://pastebin.com/zrbTjj1B

Comment: @D.Stark: Может быть есть разница между `Name` и `x:Name`.

Comment: У меня вот это не работает: https://pastebin.com/sstpctyM. А разницы между `Name` и `x:Name` нет. Давайте искать проблему в чём то другом.

Comment: @VladD: И опять проблема оказывается надуманной! Всё дело было в том, что я переопределяю в своём проекте стиль ScrollViewer (как и стиль TextBox). И вот этот самый стиль, есс-но, применялся и к `PART_ContentHost` в стиле TextBox'а =) В итоге проблема решается `Style={x:Null}` для `PART_ContentHost`.

Comment: @VladD: Помните наш диалог по различиям событий тачпада и мыши (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59462/discussion-between-vladd-and-d-stark)? Дело в том, что проблема так и не была решена ): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674245/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-listview

Comment: @D.Stark: Фу ты ну ты :) Это показывает, почему всегда имеет смысл написать изолированный пример.

Comment: Дак я так и сделал. Надо бы это вообще за правило брать!